# как указать файл для распознавания речи?

Tags: google-cloud, google-speech-recognition

cloud.google.com/speech-to-text

```
{
  "audio": {
    "content": "/* Your audio */"
  },
  "config": {
    "enableAutomaticPunctuation": true,
    "encoding": "LINEAR16",
    "languageCode": "ru-RU",
    "model": "default"
  }
}
```

Как узнать в каком виде должно быть это /* Your audio */ ?

Даю абсолютный путь, получаю:

> Invalid value at 'audio.content' (TYPE_BYTES), Base64 decoding failed
>   for \"E:/OSPanel/domains/test.test/videos/file_50.mp4\

Answer (score 0):

перевёл путь на base64.ru, дело двинулось дальше